# Reversing part of a string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Let's say I have a string stored in a variable:

```
a = 'Python'
```

Now, `a[2:4]` returns `th`. How do I reverse this part of the string so that I get `ht` returned instead?

This is what I tried:

```
print a[2:4:-1]
```

But this returned an empty string. Now I know that I can simply store the result of `a[2:4]` in a new variable and reverse that new variable. But is there a way to reverse part of a string without creating a new variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = 'Python'
>>> a[2:4]
'th'
```

Reverse the substring using `[::-1]`

```
>>> a[2:4][::-1]
'ht'
```

or adjust indexes:

```
>>> a[3:1:-1]
'ht'
```

Comment: Adjusting indexes seems to be the mist efficient since it doesnt create another temp list.

Answer (score 2):

You have to swap the start and end offsets. Did you try `a[3:1:-1]`? Of course, you have to follow the usual way: initial offset is taken while the end offset isn't (this is why I changed 4 to 3 and 2 to 1).